почему у меня персонаж не двигается в право?
код:
extends Node2D
var walk10=+10
var walk2=-10
func _process(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
        $gg.position.x+=walk2
func walk(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right"):
        $gg.position.x+=walk10

